# Add a file to project

Tags: android, file

I need to write an application that modify a `"PDF template"` file that contain some form inside.
 
My application should make a copy of that template, fill form inside and save it with an arbitrary name (keeping the original template for other tasks).
How can I add that file into my project, and retrieve it inside my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually such files are put in the `asset` folder of your project.

Then you can access the file by using

```
getAssets().open("filename");
```

in the case of opening a text file with a stream reader use

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("filename.txt")));
```

I don't know the 'protocol' required to open/edit pdf files.